# how can i use exec instead of header

Tags: php

I am using `header(Location:"http:\\example.com\enrollments\export");`

Actually my requirement is I want to execute http:\test.com\enrollments\export.php link inside another file but after executed this file it will not redirect to http:\test.com\enrollments\export. It will be stay on this www.test.com/test.php.

Example:-

### test.php

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://example.com/enrollments/export');
?>
```

### export.php

```
if(isset($data) && $data != ''){
        foreach ($data as $key=>$enrollment):

        $array1[] =  array($enrollment['Enrollment']['created'], $enrollment['Enrollment']['last_name'], $enrollment['Enrollment']['first_name']
        );
        endforeach;
    }

    $list1 = array(
    array('Sign Date', 'Last Name', 'First Name'))

    ;
    $list =  array_merge_recursive($list1, $array1); 
    $fp = fopen(WWW_ROOT.'excelimport/test/'.'Report_'.date('Y_m_d H:i:s').'.xls', 'w+'); //echo WWW_ROOT;
    $f = 'Report_'.date('Y_m_d H:i:s').'.xls';
    foreach ($list as $fields) {
      fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t", ' ');
    }
```

Comment: you just want to execute the php file and not redirect, that the core right?

Comment: Your question implies header and exec are related? How can I use a jackhammer instead of a pancake?

Answer (score 1):

In test.php create a link with the href itself Just pass a parameter with href  `www.test.com/test.php?export=1`

in test.php

```
if(isset($_GET['export']) && $_GET['export']){

include_once("enrollments/export.php");
}
```

Comment: this would be better: `include(__DIR__."/enrollments/export.php");`. No need for "once" and absolute fs-path is not the same as absolute http-path

Comment: 1. the path which you use is NOT relative (it starts with slash) 2. relative is calculated against "current-working-dir" which isn't always the same as the location of the file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
header('Location: http://test.com/enrollments/export');
```

Use

```
include "export.php" #assuming that export.php and test.php are in the same directory
```

This will run **export.php** without breaking the execution flow in **test.php** and without redirection. It's the simplest solution for your case!

Answer (score -1):

you can use curl http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

```
    <?php 
$curl = curl_init('http://example.com'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
$result = curl_exec($curl); 
echo $result; 
?>
```